# WSO2CEP 3.0.0 selecting previously defined event formatter when exporting stream

Tags: wso2

On WSO2Cep, I defined an event formatter. When defining an execution plan, I want to choose this event formatter in export stream section. But in combo box labeled "Event Formatter", available options are Default Event Formatter and Custom Event Formatter. How can I link to my previously defined event formatter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WSO2 CEP 3.0.0, linking between Event builders, Execution plans and Event Formatters happen through Streams. So when you create an event formatter, you must have selected a corresponding stream. This will be stream sending data into the event formatter.

When defining the execution plan, you simply need to set that stream as an exported stream for the execution plan. The option of 'Default Event Formatter' vs 'Custom Event Formatter' simply specifies whether a default event formatter is generated or not. When you set an exported stream for the execution plan and if that stream already has an event formatter, events processed from the execution plan will automatically be sent to that event formatter.

Thanks,
Lasantha